# How to copy paste from a vim split text to terminal

Tags: terminal

I open vim and have the following code:

```
1 a = range(10)
2 for b in a:
3     print(b)
```

I then open an ipython within vim by typing:

```
:term ipython
```

I yank the code by doing `:1,2y` and then go over to the ipython terminal and do "" to paste the yanked code.

The **problem** I have is that the spaces are not respected as shown below. Notice how `print(a)` is a lot further to the right compared to before.

```
In [2]: for a in b:
   ...:         print(a)
   ...:
```

I've seen this behaviour before when pasting things into a normal vim using -V however usually some version of set paste, set nopaste works. Though in this case it didn't.

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

thank you

I'm running ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.
Vim installation info in case helpful

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Apr 10 2018 21:31:58)
Included patches: 1-1453
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +comments          +file_in_path      +linebreak         +mouse_urxvt       +quickfix          +terminal          +windows
+arabic            +conceal           +find_in_path      +lispindent        +mouse_xterm       +reltime           +terminfo          +writebackup
+autocmd           +cryptv            +float             +listcmds          +multi_byte        +rightleft         +termresponse      -X11
-autoservername    +cscope            +folding           +localmap          +multi_lang        -ruby              +textobjects       -xfontset
-balloon_eval      +cursorbind        -footer            -lua               -mzscheme          +scrollbind        +timers            -xim
+balloon_eval_term +cursorshape       +fork()            +menu              +netbeans_intg     +signs             +title             -xpm
-browse            +dialog_con        +gettext           +mksession         +num64             +smartindent       -toolbar           -xsmp
++builtin_terms    +diff              -hangul_input      +modify_fname      +packages          +startuptime       +user_commands     -xterm_clipboard
+byte_offset       +digraphs          +iconv             +mouse             +path_extra        +statusline        +vertsplit         -xterm_save
+channel           -dnd               +insert_expand     -mouseshape        -perl              -sun_workshop      +virtualedit
+cindent           -ebcdic            +job               +mouse_dec         +persistent_undo   +syntax            +visual
-clientserver      +emacs_tags        +jumplist          +mouse_gpm         +postscript        +tag_binary        +visualextra
-clipboard         +eval              +keymap            -mouse_jsbterm     +printer           +tag_old_static    +viminfo
+cmdline_compl     +ex_extra          +lambda            +mouse_netterm     +profile           -tag_any_white     +vreplace
+cmdline_hist      +extra_search      +langmap           +mouse_sgr         -python            -tcl               +wildignore
+cmdline_info      +farsi             +libcall           -mouse_sysmouse    +python3           +termguicolors     +wildmenu
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-NQEcoP/vim-8.0.1453=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=form
at-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/pytho
n3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
```

Comment: My guess is when ipython hit the colon newline it put in the indent. And then the next pasted like also had indent. Or its a tab and not actually spaces.

Comment: hm.. this seems possible, do you think there is a fix for this? Otherwise seems like a hacky solution would be to remove 4 spaces? btw the copied over extra space is `spaces` not a `tab` so everything is `spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few workarounds.

I think what @d-ben-knoble mentioned is the reason for the strange indentation.

- `%autoindent`

  - **Benefit** almost does what I want, ie allows pasting code from vim
  - **Drawback** some code still executes before having pasted the entire block if there is a space being pasted as well
  - **Drawback** have to type `%autoindent` before / after
- `%cpaste`

  - **Benefit** allows pasting exact code and executing
  - **Drawback** need to type `--` after I've pasted
  - **Drawback** can't edit once pasted
- `%edit`

  - **Benefit** allows full pasting and editing of code
  - **Drawback** due to vimception in order to avoid vim's autoindent once entered in edit mode you need to do `:set paste`. Also, there exists a pitfall that you edit the main vim process rather than the one started by IPython which itself lives in a vim subprocess.

Ultimately I think `%cpaste` or `%edit` are probably good enough workarounds for me.

I'll leave this answer sitting around in case anyone comes up with a better solution.